# How to generate access_token for grant_type password in Azure AD for MS graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have use followed these two links to generate access_token password grant_type

1. https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau-2?preview=true
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga

I used below curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/910f-90d18b56a170/oauth2/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'client_id=4b5d-bde6-0b1a09b84a5f' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=q4720z4z_6N8CU-c7qEwx2a' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'username=xxxx@yyyy.onmicrosoft.com' --data-urlencode 'password=xxxxxxx' --data-urlencode 'resource=https://graph.microsoft.com' --data-urlencode 'scope=openid'
```

Below is the response

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: 21fdd138-0bc6-49bd-8852-c7a6a3a1e600\r\nCorrelation ID: a1010714-38f6-4926-a135-568adcdada26\r\nTimestamp: 2020-12-15 16:44:37Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50126
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-12-15 16:44:37Z",
    "trace_id": "21fdd138-0bc6-49bd-8852-c7a6a3a1e600",
    "correlation_id": "a1010714-38f6-4926-a135-568adcdada26",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"
}
```

I don't know why response suggests that my credentials are in-valid even-though I'm passing right creds.

Comment: This is the most recent doc from MS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: `curl -X POST -d "client_id=clientid&scope=user.read&grant_type=password&username=sruthi@xxx &password=Srxxxx&redirect_url=https://graph.microsoft.com " https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token` can you please try this one and also error is due to invalid credentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing the same issue when I run the below query with wrong credentials
[image]

After providing the right credentials to below curl operations able to get token

```
  curl -X POST -d "client_id=clientid&scope=user.read&grant_type=password&username=username &password=password&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com " https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token
```

[image]

[image]

> Note :Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most
> scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended.
> This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and
> carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only
> use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Comment: thanks @sruthi-j-msft-identity your answer me resolve this.                                          To achieve my desired results, i had to create a new user in Azure-AD and use those creds.
For someodd reason my creds for admin/main user for Azure-Portal were throwing this error "Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password" eventhough that user exists in users list.  Could please tell us why it was like this, if can and if you know it.

Comment: It could be an issue with the credentials as it is working fine for me with an old account

Comment: Hi @sruthi-j-msft-identity,  my principal username has this kind of format "devendrajain4567890_gmail.com#EXT#@Ashore.onmicrosoft.com", can we use this username for getting access token, as i'm not able to get it. And if use email-id as uesrname it throws  error "The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the 4fd9-855b-feb28c4a05a1 directory". Though i'm able to login into azure portal with that email-ID and password. Can you please answer this small query. Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes i was able to resolve this error with below curl request.
Also had to use utf character code for special symbols in my password from this link "https://www.utf8-chartable.de/" while running the command from linux terminal, though it wasn't required for getting token via Postman

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=3621485b0bf-6384-4b5d-bde6-0b1a09b84a5f&client_secret=145236op-54782314l-c7qEwx2a-U_T_-7-43n&scope=user.read&grant_type=password&username=johndoe@yyyy.onmicrosoft.com&password=Prince%244321&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com" https://login.microsoftonline.com/7452369-45217-4208-910f-90d18b56a170/oauth2/token

 # below is the Response
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "ChannelMessage.Send Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read offline_access openid profile User.Read",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1608079489",
    "not_before": "1608075589",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Ijl3NVBGbUpfQ1NsNjhhVHJ6dFJjVXZ0c1NaWm5nckFLS3JoQmFSbY2ZTgtNDUzMC04NzhhLTg4MjBmNDJlZjQ3NiIsInBsYXRmIjoiMTQiLCJwdWlkIjoiMTAwMzIwMDEwM0M4MkJDNSIsInJoIjoiMC5BQUFBSWZocjZPcldFRVdQLTN4b2JHUlg4aHBadjJQSDRmVkpoNlBMc2RFSGF6dFRBRG8uIiwic2NwIjoiQ2hhbm5lbE1lc3NhZ2UuU2VuZCBHcm91cC5SZWFkLkFsbCBHcm91cC5SZWFkV3Jp-OlzPDtk0GTG9o5AGLcTVv6VEVOFWF2TEylgdXnTX5A4Iue7Le8OcUtFa33of_11uvZuhEcxTzY_ANEz-R5TFhZJlxeeyw",
    "refresh_token": "0.AAAAIfhr6OrWEEWP-3xobGRX8hpZv2PH4fVJh6PLsdEHaztTADo.GSfVElYY1X0hIwKK3JBkMHTamjwx9uEDeV9U8nPbEBe7w64JdaexMVJMyBeNFZOOrAda7wDGCUJq_1gv9J0k3X3QYsJafyOeuDtDckks9tLzHbD4ZJWAxN0Dnw-OaO4Tq95sa7-wozkCwC5ZWfTdeDjp6qb92SEKtQSl8YUCe340f1y_DuL6C2yMQARfgSPCTuuVz2TqMm8MjM46m4_WSz7ATK_UfzcHyywsBVYpxfgOzAA2eShbCqjMZbvab0moyvmo",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI2M2JmNTkxYS1lMWM3LTQ5ZjUtODdhMy1jYmIxZDEwNzZiM2IiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLuMCJ9."
}
```

To achieve my desired results, i had to create a new user in Azure-AD and use those creds.

For someodd reason my creds for admin/main user for Azure-Portal were throwing this error "Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password" eventhough that user exists in users list.

Comment: Use --data-urlencode for all data containing special characters, like `--data-urlencode "password=my&secret&password"`