# Get Access Token from Azure Active Directory using username and password

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a POF with Azure Active Directory because I am planning to use it later in a production application.

In Microsoft docs, the only way I found to login is being redirected to the microsoft page to provide username and password.

Is there some API I can use to get the access token providing username and password? and I can test it, for instance, using postman.

Comment: please refer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310207/how-to-generate-access-token-for-grant-type-password-in-azure-ad-for-ms-graph-ap/65313120#65313120) it may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Resource Owner Password Credentials(ROPC) flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to get access token. See the **Important** first to make sure you could use it in your application.

> - The Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. This means that you must use
>   a tenant-specific endpoint
>   ([https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenantId_or_Name%7D)) or the
>   organizations endpoint.
> - Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use ROPC.
> - Accounts that don't have passwords can't sign in through ROPC. For this scenario, we recommend that you use a different flow for your app
>   instead.
> - If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.
> - ROPC is not supported in hybrid identity federation scenarios (for example, Azure AD and ADFS used to authenticate on-premises accounts).
>   If users are full-page redirected to an on-premises identity
>   providers, Azure AD is not able to test the username and password
>   against that identity provider. Pass-through authentication is
>   supported with ROPC, however.

Try executing this request to obtain access token.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=<your-app-id>
&scope=<scopes-in-api-permissions>
&username=<username>
&password=<password>
&grant_type=password
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking to get an access token  by sending  the username and password

you can go with a postman or a curl operation

```
POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```

[image]

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=clientid&scope=user.read&grant_type=password&username=username&password=Password" https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

> Note :Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most
> scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended.
> This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and
> carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only
> use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Comment: But if I am not sending username and password I will get a token. So there is no need to send these.